# width for the username which is in a span

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to the `webDevelopment.`. Here, what I have is ,

```
<div className="user-id">
            <i className="fa fa-user-o username-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span className="user-name">username</span>
```

Now, Here what I have is the username is an email. so It may be big. Now, I want to support it upto the `tablet`.

Now, what I did is ,

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

Now, It will work if I add the width to the span.

But I am confused is there any way or what should be the fixed width so that it will work till tablet and large devices .

Comment: You should look into [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). They support responsive design.

Comment: I am using bootstrap 4

Comment: You can use Media Queries. [mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: No what I am asking is that should I use width: some pixels

Comment: Are you asking what the longest size for an email address is?

Comment: Too little context: is it as wide as viewport on tablet, are there other elements on the same row, should it goes into its own row if too large or be truncated (mmh ellipsis, your code answers latter question ^^). **What is the layout in general and extreme cases?** You could try `max-width: 100%` or `max-width: calc(100% - known width of other elements IF known);`, flex parent and flex-shrink: 1 this one, etc